# How to store a piece of a name

Tags: php

I'm trying to store a piece of the first name split as `firstName` so I can get it to store in a table. I am a beginner at php as well as programming. Any help is appriciated, thanks.

```
$Names = 'Donny P, Raph Rsa, Leo Old, Laugh Orange';

foreach ($fullnames as $fullname) {
    $nameSplit = explode(" ", $fullname);

    if ($Names == empty($nameSplit[0]) || empty($Names)){
        echo 'No First Name Here Or No Name At All';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
    } elseif ($Names == empty($nameSplit[1])){
        echo 'No Last Name Here';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
    } else{
        echo 'First Name: ' . $nameSplit[0];
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Last Name: ' . $nameSplit[1];
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Email Address: ' . $nameSplit[0] . $email;
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<br>';
    }

}
```

Below is what I'm thinking of logically in my head, I know it's not valid code but it helps getting my idea across.

```
foreach ($nameSplit as $nameSplits) {
store nameSplit[0] as $firstName;
store nameSplit[1] as $lastName;
store nameSplit[0] as $emailUser;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is the first name without separating the names? Imagine "Van Lou Chong" What is the first name?

Comment: what is `fullnames`? Moreover I would suggest a different separator instead of "space"

Comment: What is `$Names == empty($nameSplit[0])` supposed to mean? `$Names` is a string, `empty()` returns `true` or `false`, why would you compare them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you first explode the commas and then loop through each one of them.

So something like this:

```
$exp = explode(",", $Names);

foreach($exp as $names){
    $nameSplit = explode(" ", $names);
    if($nameSplit[0] == ""){ $s = 1; }else{ $s = 0; }

    $firstName = $nameSplit[$s];
    $lastName = $nameSplit[$s+1];
    //or you can loop through any other names here starting with the first position
}
```

Comment: That would work. If anything, he'd just need to look through the existing names.

Comment: Dont agree. Existing names? Hard coded methode for 5 existing names? That smells ;)

Comment: If you can loop through, it doesn't matter if they have 12142345234 names, it'll still catch them all.

Comment: Then tell me how you would find the first/lasname in "Van Lou Chong" ?

Comment: I had a seperate check to deal with commas. This does seem to work though. Thanks. Also @bub, I know it's not good for middle names or a jr. or something like that.

Comment: Unfortunatley this doesn't do what I expected. I need to store each name in firstName and lastName. This only refers back to the most recent name in the group (Laugh Orange).

Comment: I'll modify it accordingly.

Comment: Edited :) Check it out.

Comment: Still getting the most recent name unfortunately. I tried a bunch of different ways and still no luck. How would I save the iterations in an array? I think that would work better